# Error de sintaxe em Graphql

Tags: back-end, graphql

Bom dia pessoal, estou estudando Graphql sozinho e encontrei essa dificuldade, criei uma api que faz cadastros e retorna alunos, quando fui fazer uma consulta no playground ela fica dando error de sintaxe, alguém sabe o motivo da sintaxe estar errada, já li todos os erros e modifiquei e nada funciona.

[image: Minha Mutation]

[image: Minha consulta]

Answer (score 0):

Apos ficar umas horas aqui tentando e tentando, descobri que você pode fazer as declarações da variável tudo na parte abaixo e só passar ela na mutation. A imagem e muito descritível, e só olhar ai e utilizar de exemplo.

[image: Como fazer uma mutation correta]

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).